# File 'iftex.sty' not found

Tags: lyx

I'm struggling with a problem of using Lyx with hebrew on Windows. I have the latest version (2.1.4), and I try to compile this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David CLM}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hadasim CLM}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[section]

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\Pisymbol{psy}{183}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
  \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}}
  \addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{משפט}}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{משפט}

\begin{document}

\title{ניסיון}
\maketitle
משהו.    
\end{document}
```

However, it showed my an error that I don't have the file 'iftex.sty'. I downloaded it and added to Miktex, but now it shows me the error message "Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew
 script!" (6 times).

(If I try to compile a document without the use of theroems, it compiles.)

Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. Just so that you know that your .tex file is correct, I compiled it without problem on Ubuntu: https://www.dropbox.com/s/21gvj0qpxr66bkb/mwe.pdf

Comment: by the way if you do have access to Ubuntu or are interested in dual booting I can help you easily get set up with LyX + Hebrew with just a couple of commands. Hopefully someone else comes along though and knows what the problem you're facing is.

Comment: Yes, I'll be happy if you could give me the Ubuntu commands. @scottkosty

Comment: Assuming you have a fresh Ubuntu installation with git installed, run this command: `git clone https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu.git`. Then `cd` into the directory: `cd install-tl-ubuntu`. Then do `sudo ./install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew`. That will take a while (to install TeX Live) so get it running before you go to bed. Read the options with `./install-tl-ubuntu --help` . That's it. After that restart your computer, install LyX and your document should compile.